# Stored Procedure With an Optional Parameter Limiting Rows Returned if Specified

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, top

How would one go about having a sproc that allows a consumer to **optionally** specify the number of rows returned?

If no row count is specified, then all rows returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "easiest" way is to parameterize input to TOP. The number I'm using is the maximum value for BIGINT. You'll probably never have more rows than this returned by a query.

```
USE master
GO 

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Limiter (@Top BIGINT = 9223372036854775807)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT TOP (@Top) *
FROM sys.databases

END

EXEC dbo.Limiter @Top = 1

EXEC dbo.Limiter
```

Just be careful, because you can introduce parameter sniffing symptoms here.

If you review the plans for both of these, the TOP operator for both is [expecting one row](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1wgHd_5G).

Whichever input to top executes first will be cached, unless you recompile, or add an OPTIMIZE FOR hint.

You should also be aware that adding a TOP operator may introduce [row goals](https://sqlperformance.com/2018/02/sql-plan/setting-and-identifying-row-goals).